# Find the number of lines in a div

Tags: jquery, html, logic

I want to show 'View All' kind of link, only when the lines in the div has reached 4 lines.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    3PAS-Pub-IO-doubleclick.net-LI, ATOM_DFP_Pub_LI, AUG12_Zynga.com_MafiaWars2_0.10$_CPM,
    ATOM_Macro_Jivox Testing,   Sep 11 Head and Shoulder Innovation - Do Not Bill, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_Second, 
    July 11_Affinity.com_Fiat Linea_CPL 55, 3PAS-Pub-IO-atdmt.com-LI, 2_Affinity_RealEstate_CPC_2.8_INR_2nd,
    AUG12_Zynga.com_treasureIsle_0.10$_CPM, AUG12_Zynga.com_theville_0.10$_CPM, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_NonIndia,
    AUG12_Zynga.com_RubyBlast_0.10$_CPM, 12_Affinity_Education_CPC_2.8_INR_1st, 728x90_Original, 300x250_TagModified,
    Dec11_ WhyteFort_CPL_INR 45, AUG12_Zynga.com_PetsVille_0.10$_CPM, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_First,
    AUG12_Zynga.com_FishVille_0.10$_CPM, 3PAS-Pub-IO-adfac.net-LI,
    3PAS-Pub-IO-bs.serving-sys.com-LI1, 3PAS-test-pub-IO-li, 160x600_Noscr...
</div>
```

Tried with jquery substring concept, but no luck,

I tried like

1. find div height
2. find line height
3. div height / line height = no of lines

This is the code:

```
var divheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").height();
var lineheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").css('line-height');
console.log(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));
```

But have no success, Can you guys, help me out

Comment: Why didn't it work ? Where's your code ?

Comment: I don't think there is an entirely reliable method, but your concept it sound. Post your code and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for delay, 
var divheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").height();
  var lineheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").css('line-height');
  console.log(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));

Comment: @ManojKumar Doesn't `css('line-height')` return a string with "px/em" included?

Comment: @ManojKumar I have edited your question to add the code. Next time you can do it yourself by clicking the `edit` button above your question.

Comment: The `CSS` property `line-height` is normally not a numeric value, instead it is set as `normal`, `large` etc. Hence, you don't get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ThreeDots plugin for jQuery: http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/

When calling `ThreeDots()` on your `<div>`, set `max_rows` to `4`. Just look at the examples on that page, you can also set your custom "read more" link. But beware that you have to wrap your text into an extra `<span>`, like so:

```
<div class="text_here">
    <span class="ellipsis_text">
        your text
    </span>
</div>
```

... the jQuery code line would then be:

```
$('.text_here').ThreeDots({ max_rows:4 });
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem with your code is that if you don't specify a line-height, the `line-height` default value is `normal`.

```js
$(function() {
  var divheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").height();
  var lineheight = parseInt($("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").css('line-height'), 10);
  console.log("Number of lines:", Math.round(divheight / lineheight));
});
```

```css
#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startegy-sections-targeting-exclude">
  3PAS-Pub-IO-doubleclick.net-LI, ATOM_DFP_Pub_LI, AUG12_Zynga.com_MafiaWars2_0.10$_CPM, ATOM_Macro_Jivox Testing, Sep 11 Head and Shoulder Innovation - Do Not Bill, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_Second, July 11_Affinity.com_Fiat Linea_CPL 55, 3PAS-Pub-IO-atdmt.com-LI,
  2_Affinity_RealEstate_CPC_2.8_INR_2nd, AUG12_Zynga.com_treasureIsle_0.10$_CPM, AUG12_Zynga.com_theville_0.10$_CPM, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_NonIndia, AUG12_Zynga.com_RubyBlast_0.10$_CPM, 12_Affinity_Education_CPC_2.8_INR_1st, 728x90_Original, 300x250_TagModified,
  Dec11_ WhyteFort_CPL_INR 45, AUG12_Zynga.com_PetsVille_0.10$_CPM, 123Greetings - IN Do Not Pay_First, AUG12_Zynga.com_FishVille_0.10$_CPM, 3PAS-Pub-IO-adfac.net-LI, 3PAS-Pub-IO-bs.serving-sys.com-LI1, 3PAS-test-pub-IO-li, 160x600_Noscr...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `$("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").css('line-height');` if you haven't specified a line-height. in javascript you can use this :

```
var element = document.getElementById('startegy-sections-targeting-exclude');
var lineheight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("lineHeight");
```